# Python + Flask + Discord: How to send a message through discord through a flask endpoint?

Tags: python, flask, discord.py

I'm trying to send a message with discord, activated through a Flask endpoint

I get the following error message when I call `http://127.0.0.1:5000/send`

```
RuntimeError: There is no current event loop in thread 'Thread-4'.
```

I have the following (minimal) code

```
import discord
from flask import Flask, jsonify

async def my_background_task():

  for message in ['a', 'b']:
    await client.wait_until_ready()
    channel = client.get_channel(CHANNEL_ID)
    await channel.send(message)

  await client.close() 

def sendMessages():
  client = discord.Client()
  client.loop.create_task(my_background_task())
  client.run('SECRET')

app = Flask(__name__)


@app.route('/send')
def send():
  sendMessages()
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Maybe you should consider using webhooks instead of a bot. Here is a simple example you should implement flask to it.

```py
import requests #dependency

url = "<your url>" #webhook url, from here: https://i.imgur.com/aT3AThK.png

data = {}
#for all params, see https://discordapp.com/developers/docs/resources/webhook#execute-webhook
data["content"] = "message content"
data["username"] = "custom username"

#leave this out if you dont want an embed
data["embeds"] = []
embed = {}
#for all params, see https://discordapp.com/developers/docs/resources/channel#embed-object
embed["description"] = "text in embed"
embed["title"] = "embed title"
data["embeds"].append(embed)

result = requests.post(url, json=data, headers={"Content-Type": "application/json"})

try:
    result.raise_for_status()
except requests.exceptions.HTTPError as err:
    print(err)
else:
    print("Payload delivered successfully, code {}.".format(result.status_code))

#result: https://i.imgur.com/DRqXQzA.png
```

Comment: I am extremely grateful for your help. I have been trying to get this bot working for an entire day and your solution worked right out of the box! Thanks Abdulaziz

Answer (score 5):

Sometimes using webhooks cannot provide the required functionality.

If it is possible for you to switch from flask to quart, you can use the direct support for async methods to [gain controll over the event loop](https://pgjones.gitlab.io/quart/how_to_guides/event_loop.html) as you intented to do in your given example.

The following snippet starts the discord bot within the same event loop as the quart server.

```
@app.before_serving
async def before_serving():
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    await client.login(TOKEN) # this could be done outside of this method

    # do not use client.run
    loop.create_task(client.connect())
```

A complete minimal working example would look like follows

```
import discord
import asyncio
from quart import Quart

app = Quart(__name__)
client = discord.Client()


@app.before_serving
async def before_serving():
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    await client.login(TOKEN)
    loop.create_task(client.connect())


@app.route("/send", methods=["GET"])
async def send_message():
    # wait_until_ready and check for valid connection is missing here
    channel = client.get_channel(CH_ID)
    await channel.send('XYZ')
    return 'OK', 200


app.run()
```

The [connect](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Client.connect) of the client could be triggered by the `/send` method itself, however it is important to not create a new task at every request.